# How to generate the attendance report of Google Meet Participants

Tags: google-apps-script

How can I pull up the list of participants in google meet, I need to generate the customized report for the participants, e.g; Email, No of Minutes, Name of the participant

Comment: I think Google details that here unless I'm missing some details. https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/editors/sheets/quickstart/attendance

Answer (score 0):

If you have the Business Plus or higher version of Google Workspace, attendance tracking is included as part of the plan.  After adding Google Meet to the calendar invite, select "Change Conference Settings" and there should be a checkbox for Attendance Tracking.  If that is toggled to be on, then at the end of the Google Meet an email will be sent to the event creator with a Google Sheet.  The sheet will have a row for each attendee, with columns of Name, Email, Duration, Time joined, and Time Exited.